# Word Frequency in a WikiPedia Article

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, information-retrieval, mediawiki-api, information-extraction

How can i get the frequency of a specified word in a wikipedia Article without storing the whole article and then process it ? For eg , How may times the word "India" occurs in this article https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple-minded example that reads the web page line by line. But there is no guarantee the HTML is broken into *lines*.  (It is in this case, over 1300 of them.)

```
import re
import urllib.request
from collections import Counter

URL = 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/India'

counter = Counter()

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as source:
    for line in source:
        words = re.split(r"[^A-Z]+", line.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.I)
        counter.update(words)

for word in ['India', 'Indian', 'Indians']:
    print('{}: {}'.format(word, counter[word]))
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
India: 547
Indian: 75
Indians: 11
>
```

This also counts terms if they appear in the HTML structure of the page, not just the content.

If you want to focus on content, consider the [Pywikibot python library](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) which uses the preferred MediaWiki API to extract content, though it appears to be based on a "complete page at a time" model which you noted you're trying to avoid.  Regardless, that module's documentation points to a list of similar, but more advanced, packages that you might want to review.

Comment: its an old answer but let me try: Is it possible to count how many times  a specific word appear in whole english wikipedia dump ?

Comment: You can list words by usage using [this](https://github.com/Common-Voice/cv-sentence-extractor) and [this](https://github.com/dabinat/cvtools/).